# With Word VBA, can I divide the code module of a Form into two code modules?

Tags: vba, forms, module, ms-word

In my Word file, I have a form called MyNiceForm. There is a code module associated with it, of course, which contains the _Click() routines. (Maybe those are called event handlers, but that doesn't affect my question.)

I have so many _Click() routines that I'd like to split them into a separate code module, but I can't quite figure out how to do that. I'm somewhat sure that VBA does not allow me to put a _Click() routine in a regular code module (a 'non-Form' code module).

Comment: Looks like an X-Y problem. If you have so much code-behind that the form is becoming a mess that's hard to navigate (but it still works fine), try putting it up on [codereview.se] and see what advice you get there to clean it up. You might learn a thing or two about OOP and design patterns in VBA ;-)

Answer (score 2):

No, the `Click` routines have to stay in the UserForm code module. In the strictest sense, the UserForm is a *class* within the document "container". The UserForm designer and the code module are both part of the class / UserForm object. All the buttons' "Click" routines depend on this link.

(This is a similar situation with the Document, itself, and the `ThisDocument` module in a document's VBA project. The Document is a class/object and `ThisDocument` the code module. ActiveX controls (which are UserForm controls) on the document surface also rely on the link between the visual part and the code.)

What you *can* do is move the code inside the Click procedures to another (plain) module. Leave just one line of code in the procedure that "calls" the code in that module. If the code works with the UserForm and/or controls on it you need to pass these objects as arguments.

That could look like this:

```
'Code in the UserForm module
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
  CheckBoxClick Me, Me.CheckBox1
End Sub

'Code in a regular module
Sub StartUserForm()
    Dim frm As frmTest

    Set frm = New frmTest
    frm.Show
End Sub

Sub CheckBoxClick(frm As frmTest, ck As MSForms.CheckBox)
    Debug.Print frm.NAME, ck.Caption, ck.value
    frm.CheckBox2.value = Not ck.value        
End Sub
```